# Highchart multi axes labels not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have 3 x-axis but their labels are not visible. 
The whole idea is to have the bars thiner, and enought room for the labels

http://jsfiddle.net/rnz9ybuq/1/

```
xAxis: [
            {
                categories: ['01/14', '02/14', '03/14'],
                title: {
                    text: "left column"
                }
            },
            {

                categories: ['stuff 1', 'stuff 2', 'stuff 3'],
                opposite: true,
                title: {
                    text: "1st right column"
                }

            },
            {
                opposite: true,
                title: {
                    text: "2nd right column"
                },
                categories: ['thing 1', 'thing 2', 'thing 3' ]
            }
        ],
        yAxis: {
            opposite: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: "Data"
            }
        },
```

[image: The bad result]

I guess I'm missing something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have reference to the xAxis (`xAxis:2`) in the serie.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rnz9ybuq/2/